"Title cannot contain" oddities: Why is the term "Android app" not allowed in a title?
I came across a question with the title "Connecting Android Studio to Spotify API", which is total nonsense, as you don't connect Android Studio to Spotify API, but the Android app you develop in Android Studio.
As the IDE you use for developing the app is of no relevance to the question, I tried to change it to "Using Spotify API in an Android app", which was rejected. The first oddity is that the rejection text marks the whole title as rejected instead of the term "Android app", which causes the rejection. (By multiple tries I found that "Android app" causes the rejection.)
This is not the first time that the Stack Overflow title checker prevented me from updating titles that were total nonsense, and my corrected title was rejected.
So the question arises why Android developers are not allowed to use "Android app" in the title, and even more important, why the title rejection is so intransparent and frustrating. (If someone else is better in (re)writing titles, please post examples of alternative titles that pass the rejection system in the comments.)
I don't know how many new Stack Overflow users are confronted with such an oddity which IMHO has very little effect on the title and question quality.

TBH, you also don't connect an Android app to an API. It sounds like you have to plug in a power cable or something. As if it's done once. Each individual API call can "connect" (work) or not. There can be an SDK or something that does some of the work for you but "connect" is definitely not the verb you use when you want to do this. The fact that "android app" is rejected seems circumstantial. The task is to integrate with Spotify. Reading the question, it's specifically about acquiring authentication. So trying to change "android studio" to "android app" doesn't significantly improve it

@VLAZ As I wrote in the question I wanted to change it to Using Spotify API in an Android app So nothing with connect is in my updated title.

obligatory The title word filter is one of the worst ideas ever implemented on SO ...

The easy fix is to avoid the word "app", it adds little value (if you're developing for Android, it's probably an app) and bypasses the block, Using Spotify API in Android sounds like a better title to me.

In most cases IMX, the filter is really complaining about the title being too short - and thus failing to include enough useful stuff.

I suspect that something like `How to use the Spotify API in an Android App?" would have likely be acceptable though.

I've edited the title of that question to be more specific.

@rene it's not entirely useless, but maybe certain users could be exempt

If those keywords were allowed every question in the tag would likely contain them. The issue is that when using search engines the tagged keywords are included and they don't need to be in the title, see Should questions include "tags" in their titles?. Sometimes, writing a syntactically correct sentence can by itself almost demand the inclusion of the tagged keywords, then it's generally best to put them at the end of the title. However, with extremely popular keywords/brands that tend to be misused having the system filter for them can be best.
